# Alternate for if-else

Tags: c#, if-statement

Below is my code:

```
int a = 4;
if (a > 3)
{
    Label1.Text = "Hello";
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "Hi!";
}
//Alternate for if-else
Label1.Text = (a > 3) ? "Hello" : "Hi!";
```

As we know, both if-else and alternate for if-else gives out same output. I was wondering, what if i have more than one statement. For Instance

```
int a = 4;
if (a > 3)
{
    Label1.Text = "Hello";
    Label2.Text = "How are you?";
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "Hi";
    Label2.Text = "How do you do"";
}
```

So, is there an alternate for this? I am sure there is something C# has to offer which I can use. Thanks in Advance.

P.S. I am fairly new to C#

Comment: Have you ever heard of Switch Case?

Comment: what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: If it is clear, it has no side effects, it is easy to document, then why change it?

Comment: You can try "else if" or a "switch case" statement, or try the answers below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is probably the best solution. It is very easy to read and see exactly what you're doing.
Using the ternary operator even for one statement can sometimes be a bit much to read depending on your code.

There are a huge number of alternatives here. You could say that many OOP design patterns are themselves just alternatives to if statements, but for a simple case like this it is unnecessary to go that far.

Comment: agree, if the code is shorter, doesn't mean it's more readable (better?). This is shown nicely in Clean Code book by Uncle Bob, maybe sometimes controversial

Comment: how about switch case

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Why `switch-case` if condition fits for `if-else`?

Comment: @Ilya Ivanov: The question is what makes code 'readable'... Isn't it just another subjective feeling?

Comment: @st4hoo i would say what code reduces time to understand it - that code is more readable, as to compare to other code, which requires more time. Time required to understand code is an objective metric, which doesn't depend on subjective feeling of beauty.

Comment: @Ilya Ivanov: The problem is that something that is easy to understand by you might by hard to understand by another person(and vice versa)... So, `readability` exists only in particular group context. There is no objective `readability`...

Comment: @st4hoo You're right, I didn't address the question correctly. Given the context I think the answer is appropriate. I'll edit the question just to reiterate what everyone else here is saying: there are innumerable alternatives, but they are unnecessary here.

Comment: @st4hoo by "objective" I meant the metric by which I measure readability, not readability per se

Answer (score 3):

The way you have already implemented this is already fine.

Perhaps something like this may help. It abstracts the implementation code away from the `if`, assuming that is what you would like:

```
int a = 4;
if (a > 3)
{
    SetLabelToHello();
}
else
{
    SetLabelToHi();
}

// ....

public void SetLabelToHello()
{
    Label1.Text = "Hello";
    Label2.Text = "How are you?";
}

public void SetLabelToHi()
{
    Label1.Text = "Hi";
    Label2.Text = "How do you do";
}
```

Using methods in this way allows you to easily add more statements to the `if` condition whilst keeping clean, easily maintainable code.

Comment: Hint: you may remove curly brackets in your `if-else` statement: `if (a > 3)   SetLablesToHello();  else    SetLabelsToHi();`

Comment: This is true. Personally, I prefer the curly braces as I feel they improve readability, but each to his own in that regard :)

Answer (score 3):

Move assignment to a function

```
public int SetLabels(string label1text, string label2text)
{
   try
   {
        Label1.Text = label1text;
        Label2.Text = label2text;

        return 0;
   }
   catch
   {
        return 1;
   }
}


var result = a > 3 ? SetLabels("Hello", "How are you?") : SetLabels("Hi!", "How do you do");
```

Comment: would it be better to use `void` return type for `SetLabels` and call it withing plain-old `if-else` statement? Does functional paradigm restrict `if-else` statements somehow?

Comment: I agree with your approach of moving the assignments to a method. But the exception handling and the return value should be left away. They are overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score 2):

C# is an imperative language, so this is the way it should be written. There is no built in approach to have the double-assignment, because C# does not support multiple return values.

Just keep it like this. It's good.

Answer (score 2):

Tim Schmelter gave an answer before, but there come some DRY principals and down-voted hard.

His answer was ok:

```
Label1.Text = a > 3 ? "Hello" : "Hi";
Label2.Text = a > 3 ? "How are you?" : "How do you do?";
```

If you are too much about DRY, then do it like this

```
bool veryDryCondition = a > 3;
Label1.Text = veryDryCondition ? "Hello" : "Hi";
Label2.Text = veryDryCondition ? "How are you?" : "How do you do?";
```

Though using simple `if` is still preferable way in this case.

I am using `?:` mostly for better readability, if conditions are unique and I want to keep *one-liners* (code what stay in one line) for better readability. If conditions are common and there are more than one actions - using `if` is usually better.

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** "So, is there an alternate for this?"

**A:** Yes, there is **infinite** quantity of alternatives. BUT it dosn't mean that you have to use them... Everything depends on your context.

Here is another weird, possible solution. It works, but does it make sense?

```
Action action;
int a = 4;

if (a > 3)
{
    action = new Action(() => {
        Label1.Text = "Hello";
        Label2.Text = "How are you?";
    });

}
else
{
    action = new Action(() => {
        Label1.Text = "Hi";
        Label2.Text = "How do you do"";
    });
}

action();
```

Comment: You forgot to add a singleton factory of factories, that uses dictionary to dispatch actions :)

Comment: @Ilya Ivanov: I was rather thinking about evolution in CoR pattern direction ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no, there isn't an alternative / shorter way of writing this. Although there are other ways to do it.

Which then leads on to why do you want to make the code more concise? it is better to strive for readability and better maintenance.

```
int a = 4;
var aIsGreaterThanThree = (a > 3)
if (aIsGreaterThanThree)
{
   SetLabelsToHello();
}
else 
{
   SetLabelsToHi();
}

void SetLablesToHello()
{  
   Label1.Text = "Hello";
   Label2.Text = "How are you?";
}

void SetLabelsToHi() 
{
   Label1.Text = "Hi";
   Label2.Text = "How do you do";
}
```

At that point depending on perference you could change the if statement back to the shorthand version or drop the { and } from the if statements.

Comment: Hint: you may remove curly brackets in your `if-else` statement: `if (aIsGreaterThanThree)
  SetLablesToHello();
 else 
  SetLabelsToHi();`

Comment: @st4hoo I put that at the end as a side note, whilst you can do that, it can sometimes lead to the introduction of bugs so for the answer I left them in, in practice I would leave them out.

Answer (score 1):

You want one conditional operator for both labels? That's not possible, but what's wrong with:

```
Label1.Text = a > 3 ? "Hello" : "Hi!";
Label2.Text = a > 3 ? "How are you?" : "How do you do";
```

If both labels are not related and the condition might change in future, so that the first label has a different one than the other, then this approach is better. Otherwise stick with the `if-else` since it doesn't repeat the same condition multiple times.

Comment: Well, DRY is the problem ? If the condition change, isn't it better to change it only in one place ? (not downvoting by the way, just an opinion)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: it's only repetition if the condition is always the same for both labels. Otherwise the conditional operator is better since it more readable in this case and allows to change the condition separately.

Comment: Oh, absolutely in this case, yes !